# Try catch asynchronously

Tags: swift, try-catch

I have these methods:

```
open func promptNow() throws {
    // show an alert view
}

open func promptAfter(dalay: TimeInterval) throws {
    try self.promptNow()
}
```

This code compile well, but obviously I need to call `try self.promptNow()` inside an asynchronous block such as:

```
open func promptAfter(dalay: TimeInterval) throws {
    let dispatchTime = DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
    queue.asyncAfter(deadline: dispatchTime) {
       try self.promptNow()  
    }
}
```

This produce an error:

> Invalid conversion from throwing function of type () -> throws () to
>   non-throwing function type ()->Void

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: There is no `dispatch_after` in Swift 3 so your code makes no sense at this point. Provide actual up-to-date code we can test with.

Comment: *How can I fix this issue* - by not throwing or by wrapping it in a `do` clause. `promptAfter` will not rethrow the exception, how could it, its caller has already continued and the exception would go nowhere

Comment: Why do people down vote questions like this? The question is clear. The question shows relevant code. It shows effort. What else do people want from a question?

Answer (score 6):

You cannot make an asynchronous function throwable, since the caller of such function would continue execution right after calling the async method and hence couldn't catch an error that would be thrown after the async method returned.

You can either specify your function to take a closure as an input argument and [make that closure throwable](https://appventure.me/2015/06/19/swift-try-catch-asynchronous-closures/) or handle the error inside the function instead of re-throwing it.

All code below is written in Swift3. I have used the `main` thread for executing `promptNow` since if you are presenting an alert controller, that needs to happen on the main thread.

Throwable closure solution (since you are not actually using the closure to return any value, I wouldn't recommend using this solution):

```
open func promptAfter(delay: TimeInterval, completion: @escaping (_ inner: () throws -> Void) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+delay) {
        do {
            try self.promptNow()
            completion({})
        } catch {
            completion({throw error})
        }
    }
}
```

You call it like this:

```
promptAfter(delay: 5, completion: { inner in
    do {
        try inner()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
})
```

Solution handling the error inside `promptAfter`:

```
open func promptAfter(delay: TimeInterval) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+delay) {
        do {
            try self.promptNow()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, but using an error handler instead of a completion handler would probably make more sense here

Comment: What do you mean by an error handler? If you mean the second option, I also think that is a better solution as I have mentioned in my answer as well, but I wanted to show all alternatives I know of.

Comment: I mean that the callee passes a closure that accepts an error as a parameter and only gets called when one appears

Comment: So you mean instead of throwing the error in the closure, return the error in the closure without throwing it?